# Why Business Class router don't usually include ADSL?

Tags: router, adsl, cisco-small-business, modem

I am shopping for a good VPN router to replace my terrible stock ADSL modem + router from my ISP, which need to be restarted 4 times a day. This is for my office use, which connected by around 17 devices or more in the future, and also able to setup a VPN for my sales person to access intranet web server.

While searching around, I find that most business router don't come with ADSL2+ connection. This mean I need to spend money for a modem too.

My question is, why don't they design a modem + router device just like consumer router?

And when I search for "business modem", I don't get much useful result... How do small business design their Network and connect to internet?

Comment: Actually, ADSL is normally a consumer-grade or SOHO network connection. Real business-grade networks usually are different.

Comment: such routers exist but they are expensive, more than a typical 2 box solution

Comment: Since it is too difficult to obtain pure modem device, we need to buy a modem+router device, and a business class router, and configure bridge for them?

Comment: You got two answers that really say the same thing, and they are correct. You really are not going to get a different answer, and the answer may not be what you want to hear, but you should pick one and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "business class" implies use in many situations where the service may be supplied by something other than ADSL. Combined router/modems are pretty much a home/consumer niche device.

- Getting your signal via DOCSIS cable? ADSL is useless to you.
- Got a Fiber line? - ADSL is useless to you.
- Got an ethernet feed from a provider in your office building? ADSL is
  useless to you.

Likewise, a true "business class" router is hardly ever *also* a WiFi access point (and if it claims to be the one and has the other built in, I'll tend to regard its claims of business-class as bogus until proven otherwise.) Meanwhile most consumers don't even know the difference between the two functions.

Answer (score 3):

A DSL or DOCSIS modem is a specialized bridging device.

Including one in a router is either a cheap gimmick or increases the expense of a business device that will limit its adoption.

Spring for the ADSL2+ modem and you will both probably never have to replace it and will have every option under the sun for routers.

Comment: Exactly, but it is very difficult to find one device with only modem capabilities, is either router, or modem+router. Which device you recommend?

Comment: @VHanded, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on most SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] or [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: I agree with Ron Maupin.  It's not about the manufacturer but the framework that you intend to have a modem separate from your other network gear.  It is only an aspect of your partnership with your ISP.  The rest of your network is entirely your concern.